# scss does not work with vue3 app (TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function)

Tags: webpack, sass, vuejs3, scss-lint

I am trying to use scss in the vue3 app. I get following error.

> ./src/components/SinglePost.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=164ef990&lang=scss
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/components/SinglePost.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=164ef990&lang=scss)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
> at Object.loader (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:25:24)

I have followed the instructions given on https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html page. I am using `vue-cli-service serve` to start the server.
Code in the singlepost.vue is as follow, I am not sure if creation of webpack.config.js file would be necessary if this command is used to start the service.

```
<style lang="scss">
.btn {
    &,
    &:link,
    &:visited {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10rem;
    transition: all .3s;
    position: relative;
    //  
    }
.....etc etc 
</style>
```

Please guide me, I am new to web development.

Comment: Hey maybe a bit late, but I have downgraded my sass-loader to 10.1.1 using the command: npm install sass-loader@^10.1.1

Answer (score 7):

Or run

```
npm install -D sass-loader@10.1.1 sass
```

Answer (score 0):

These two packages solved the issue,

```
"node-sass": "^4.0.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.0.0"
```

Comment: also see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/923